# Connect two nodejs servers

Tags: node.js

I have 2 servers Nodejs include e-commerce server and payment server. How can I connect these servers with HTTPS protocol and token-based for payment server to communicate with e-commerce server?

Comment: For authentication JWT (https://jwt.io/) tokens would work perfectly, and for HTTPS communication basically use axios (https://stackabuse.com/making-asynchronous-http-requests-in-javascript-with-axios/)

Comment: How about socket.io? Does it related to this situation? By the way, thanks for your recommendation!